# Difference between function declarations in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, module

I read some information about modular JavaScript programming, however I haven't been able to find the advantage of `new function () {}` declaration.

What is the main difference in two declarations below:

```
var obj = {};
obj.calculate = new function () {};
```

and

```
obj.calculate = function () {};
```

I would like, if anybody could explain with examples. For sure there's a lot of information on the web, but I haven't found the one that would explain in an easy way (with examples).

Comment: `new foo` calls `foo` as a constructor function and returns a new instance of `foo`. `foo` simply references the function `foo`. Big difference. In your first example, `obj.calculate` is an object. In the second example it's a function. Nor sure where you have seen `new function () {}` in particular, but I'd argue it's not that common.

Comment: if it is an object why not to use just `obj.calculate = {}`?

Comment: As I said, I doubt `new function () {}` by itself is common. If it is used somewhere, the author either has good reasons which cannot be determined just be looking at that line of code, or they have no clue about what they are doing.

Comment: Author is developing in JavaScript for several years and he used that in his API, he began the API declaration in that way. I cannot share the code because of its confidentiality.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is easier to understand, if you compare it with named functions. If `f` is a function,

- `f` compares to `function(){}`; this is just a reference to the function.
- `f(x)` compares to `function(){}(x)`; this is a function call with an argument.
- `new f` compares to `new function(){}`; this calls a constructor.
- `new f(x)` compares to `new function(){}(x)`; this calls a constructor with an argument.

In the next example, there is a function called MyFunction, which is then stored in f1, and an anonymous function, which is stored in f2.

```
function MyFunction() {
    console.log("This is a normal function.")
}
var f1 = MyFunction;
var f2 = function() {
    console.log("This is an anonymous function.")
}
console.log("f1 is a", typeof f1)
// f1 is a function
console.log("f2 is a", typeof f2)
// f2 is a function
```

In the next example, there is a constructor called MyConstructor, which is used to create a new object o1, and an anonymous constructor, which is used to create a new object o2.

```
function MyConstructor() {
    console.log("This is a constructor.")
    this.member = "created with MyConstructor"
}
var o1 = new MyConstructor;
var o2 = new function() {
    console.log("This is an anonymous constructor.")
    this.member = "created with an anonymous constructor"
}
console.log("o1 is an", typeof o1, o1.member)
// "o1 is an object created with MyConstructor"
console.log("o2 is an", typeof o2, o2.member)
// "o2 is an object created with an anonymous constructor"
```

Comment: You could just have written `var f2 = function () { this.member = "this is constructor"; }` and then calling `var o2 = new f2()` would return to you an object.

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = {};
obj.calculate = new function () { this.value = "string"; };
```

Now you can access `value` with `obj.calculate.value` and `value` is parameter of `obj.calculate` Object.

```
var obj = {};
obj.calculate = function () { this.value = "string"; };
```

Here you cannot access `value` unless you execute the function assigned to the `obj.calculate` via `obj.caluculate()`. And after execution `value` becomes parameter of `obj` not `obj.calculate`.